# Python Flask WTForms-Components PhoneNumberField Import error

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use the PhoneNumberField from WTForms-Components offcial docs are here https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#phonenumberfield

this is what i am trying `

```
from wtforms import Form
from sqlalchemy_utils import PhoneNumber
from wtforms_components import PhoneNumberField

class UserForm(Form):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        country_code='FI'
        display_format='national'
    )`
```

What i have done so  so far  is

```
sudo pip install Flask-Wtf --upgrade
sudo pip install Flask-Wtforms --upgrade
sudo pip install sqlalchemy-utils --upgrade
sudo pip install WTForms-Components --upgrade
```

Does this library even still works? 
I get this error
from wtforms_components import PhoneNumberField
ImportError: cannot import name PhoneNumberField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if `PhoneNumberField` was moved in WTForms-Components 0.10.0 to WTForms-Alchemy 0.15.0. Both packages have the same author. [Here](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-components/issues/39#issuecomment-176649583) is a GitHub issue that does a better job of explaining why it broke.

In short change your import to this:

```
from wtforms_alchemy import PhoneNumberField
```